# GIT - Rebase - How to deal with conflicts

Tags: git, conflict, rebase

I am working on a project that has two branches: `master` and `feature`

The `feature` branch was created some time ago and has numerous commits.

Since the `feature` branch was created there have been a couple of commits to `master`

At this point when I go to `rebase` off of `master` I get conflicts. I resolve them and then `rebase --continue`. Then I get conflicts again, and again resolve and `rebase --continue`. This happens over and over and many times it seems like they are the same conflicts that are appearing.

In my mind here is what is happening:

`master(commits)->a->b`
`feature(commits)->c->d->e->f->g`

`feature` was branched from `master->a` and then all commits were created.

When I `rebase` it rewinds back to the begining of `feature` where it was branched from `master` applies `master->b` and then starts to apply `feature->c` at this point it has a conflict. I resolve (accepting the `master` changes) and continue. Now it tries to apply `feature->d` and finds the same conflict. Again I have to resolve and `continue`. This happens over and over.

For example here are the changes:

```
master->a
    <div id="foo">

master->b
    <div id="bar">

feature->c
    <div id="fubar">

feature->d
    //Nothing has changed, inherited from feature->c
    <div id="fubar">
```

I am assuming that when it reaches `feature->c` it says change `foo` to `fubar` and then it notices that `foo` is already changed to `bar`. I resolve to `bar` and then it does the same logic applying `feature->d`

My two questions:

1) Is my understanding of how git is working / dealing with commits/conflicts/rebasing correct?

2) How can I avoid having to resolve the same conflicts over and over again? I was thinking of squashing all of the commits on the feature branch so that there is only one to deal with. I was not sure if this was a good idea or exactly the best way to go about squashing in the scenario.

Note, this is a very simplified example. In reality I have a lot more commits and within each numerous files with numerous conflicts. Some of them appear to be the same throughout the `rebase --continue` process and some are new for each `commit`.

My end goal is to clean up this project as simply as possible (get the feature branch rebased off the current master). I do not care about the history of the commits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I do not care about the history of the commits.

If you really don't care about history, a `git merge --squash` is going to let you resolve all your conflicts at once and produce a single commit with all the changes.

To essentially do that `--squash` in-place, you could do something like this:

```
git branch -m feature feature-old
git checkout master -b feature
git merge --squash feature-old
```

After you resolve all conflicts (once), you will create a single commit on `feature` that has `master` as a parent.

That being said, I'm a fan of keeping history. Definitely try `rerere` first. You might also try an in-place `rebase --interactive` (e.g. `git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD master)`) to squash the fixup-type commits without completely eliminating all the discrete commits.

Answer (score 21):

Your mental image is close, but let's make it exact:

```
...--o--*--A--B          <-- master
         \
          C--D--...--Z   <-- feature
```

This is what you have now: the name `master` points to *tip commit* `B` (with each single-letter or `o` or `*` representing a commit).  Each commit points back (left-ish) to its previous commit.  Two commits, `A`, and `B`, are only on `master`.  A bunch of commits are only on `feature`, namely `C` through `Z` here.  Commit `*` and all *earlier* (further-left) commits are on *both* branches.

What `git rebase` does is locate commit `*` by working backwards from commit `Z` and also from the tip of `master`.  It then knows that it needs to *copy* commits C-Z.  The copies are to start right after master.  If we use `C'` to name the copy of `C`, `D'` for the copy of `D`, and so on, the final *graph* will look like this:

```
                C'-D'-...-Z'   <-- feature
               /
...--o--*--A--B                <-- master
         \
          C--D--...--Z         [abandoned]
```

As I think you have realized, each copy is made one commit at a time, by turning each commit (which is a complete snapshot) into a set-of-changes.  To get what *changed* in `C`, Git does:

```
git diff <hash-of-*> <hash-of-C>
```

Git then tries to apply this change to the snapshot in `B`, but it doesn't apply easily, so Git tries doing a merge: it compares `*` to `B` and sees that it should change `<div id="foo">` to `<div id="bar">`, according to that; but it should change `<div id="foo">` `<div id="fubar">`, according to `*`-vs-`C`.  That's the first merge conflict.

So, you resolve this and commit (well, `git rebase --continue` commits):

```
                C'       <-- HEAD (rebase in progress)
               /
...--o--*--A--B          <-- master
         \
          C--D--...--Z   <-- feature
```

and Git goes on to copy `D`, by diffing `D` vs `C` to get a patch.

This time, there *should* be no `<div id="foo">` to `<div id="fubar">` change, so you *should not* get a merge conflict here.  To find out for sure, try `git show`-ing commit `D`, which likewise compares it to `C`, producing a diff.

You may, however, get bitten by white-space changes or similar.  It's worth taking a close look at each `git diff` output, and checking on things like end-of-line attributes if you are using those (CRLF conversions).  End of line stuff often affects every line in every file, but you can get cases of single-line problems, depending on who uses what editor, for instance.

I suspect a more likely problem: `git diff` is synchronizing on the *wrong lines*.  It finds some trivial things that match up, such as lines that read `}`, and uses those to decide that two files are back in sync and then picks out "wrong changes".  If this is the case, the cure—if there is one—is to instruct Git to use a smarter diff.  In particular, the `patience` diff tries not to synchronize on trivial lines, but rather only on significant (i.e., non-recurring) lines.  This may or may not actually help—running `git diff --diff-algorithm=patience` (or `git show` with the same argument) on your commits may tell you.  Whether you can get rebase to use a different diff algorithm depends on your Git version.

Aside from the mystery of why Git seems to be repeating the change, when it should have only *other* changes in `C`-vs-`D`, one thing you *can* do to help out is to use [`git rerere`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) to get Git to *re*-use a *re*corded *re*solution (hence the name).  Basically, when Git hits a merge conflict, if `rerere` is enabled, Git writes the conflicting parts into its database, and then when you `git add` the resolved file, Git writes the resolution (paired with the original conflict).  Then, the next time Git hits a merge conflict, it checks the saved rerere data: if the conflict is for the same patch, it pulls out the recorded resolution, and uses that without interacting with you.

You can indeed squash some or all feature commits together, by rebasing `feature` atop commit `*` (using interactive rebase).  Since these patches won't conflict with themselves—at least as long as they are played back "in order"—that can let you reduce the number of commits that require resolving.  Whether you *should* do this is up to you: in general, if you are rebasing, you get new replacement commits anyway, so you might as well make the new ones "as pretty as possible" for future debugging or other code exploration.  Clearly, it would be better to have five "does something interesting, but pretty much stand-alone" commits instead of 50 "do fragment of one thing, do another fragment, fix previous fragment, do another fragment, OK that thing is done move to next thing, oops fix tiny error, ..." so those are very good candidates for squashing-together.  But, it's usually better to have five "does one thing" commits than one "does five things" commits: it means that if there is a bug in one of the five, you can fix *that* without worrying about the other four.

Comment: So the problem is introduced in diffs. But why diffs are necessary at all? If git just stores snapshots, why not just putting `feature` on top of `master` without looking at `git diff <hash-of-*> <hash-of-C>` ? At least this is how `git rebase` is commonly presented. Replay the commits of one branch on top of another branch.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that I was resolving conflicts with `--ours` when I should have been using `--theirs`.

The reason is that `--ours` is *your* changes in a `merge`, but in a `rebase` it is `--theirs` because git effectively removes your commits and replays copies of them.

So when you resolve a conflict with your version with a `rebase` do:

`git checkout --theirs some.file
git add some.file`

but when resolving a conflict with your version with a `merge` do:

`git checkout --ours some.file
git add some.file`

Answer (score -1):

When you perform a **git rebase** operation, you're typically moving commits around. Because of this, you might get into a situation where a merge conflict is introduced. That means that two of your commits modified the same line in the same file, and Git doesn't know which change to apply.

After you reorder and manipulate commits using git rebase, should a merge conflict occur, Git will tell you so with the following message printed to the terminal:

```
error: could not apply fa39187... something to add to patch A

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply fa39187f3c3dfd2ab5faa38ac01cf3de7ce2e841... Change fake file
```

Here, Git is telling you which commit is causing the conflict (fa39187). You're given three choices:

- You can run **git rebase --abort** to completely undo the rebase. Git will return you to your branch's state as it was before git rebase was called.
- You can run **git rebase --skip** to completely skip the commit. That means that none of the changes introduced by the problematic commit will be included. It is very rare that you would choose this option.
- You can fix the conflict.

To fix the conflict, you can follow [the standard procedures for resolving merge conflicts from the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line). When you're finished, you'll need to call git rebase --continue in order for Git to continue processing the rest of the rebase.

Comment: Is this just the text from https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase ?